# Where to clear customs in Mexico?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, mexico

I am flying back to the US (Oakland) from Cancun through Guadalajara. We did not clear immigration or customs in Cancun, because the first leg was domestic, but it appears that we don’t need to clear immigration in Guadalajara, either. We were able to transfer flights without having to pass an immigration checkpoint. Currently, we are waiting at the gate in GDL. Is this any cause for worry, since it doesn’t look like we need to register an exit from Mexico?

Comment: @HenningMakholm That does answer my question. I’ll close this. Thanks for the response